# Problems with "_expected_/_unexpected_"

Tags: support

When I write, for example, `_expected_/_unexpected_`, the second word is not rendered in italic, and the underscores are visible; the same is true for `*expected*/*unexpected*`.

- *expected*/*unexpected*
- *expected*/*unexpected*

Is there a way to make appear both the words in italic, without to write space before/after the slash?
Does the markup works as expected, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Workaround method 1: Use `&#47;` instead of `/`.

> *expected*/*unexpected*

Workaround method 2: Use `<em>…</em>` instead of `_..._`

> *expected*/*unexpected*

Comment: `<em>` not `<i>`

Comment: @Yi: Why? They work both, don't they?