# Ctrl + I to italicize does not always work right

Tags: support, markdown

If I type in "test", highlight it, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, I get this:

> *test*

However, if I type in "test_test", highlight it, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, I get this:

> *test_test*

My guess is that this is because the `_` and the `*` are fighting. (`_test_` shows up as *test*.) As far as I know, there is no way to italicize a word with an underscore in it. _test_test_ does not work either.

So, there are two problems here:

1. The standard keyboard shortcut for italicizing does not always work right.
2. There is no way (that I could find) to italicize a word with an underscore in it.

So there are several ways to fix #2 (see answers below). However, they are not immediately obvious. This could be a small stumbling block for casual or new users.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with "_expected_/_unexpected_"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63466/problems-with-expected-unexpected)

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Not really a dupe; here a literal underscore should go into the output, whereas in the linked question this is not the case. And: Here the solution is to escape the `_`, in the linked question this is not a solution.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut seems to be working fine - it put asterisks around the text, as it should. The problem is solely the unescaped underscore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Escape the inner underscore with a backslash:

```
_hello\_world_
```

> *hello_world*

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't address the bug, but it's possible to italicize by using HTML instead of markdown:

```
<i>test_test</i>
```

> *test_test*

```
<em>test_test</em>
```

> *test_test*