# The title of the inserted link for a duplicate question should be properly escaped

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/can-you-explain-why-10) was recently closed as a duplicate of [(![]+[])[+[]]… Explain why this works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170978/explain-why-this-works). However, the inserted link blows up as the weird title does not get escaped properly in the resulting markdown.

[image: bad]

Of course, a point could be made that the title of the question should be changed, but it would still probably be a good idea to get the escaping right, as these characters are allowed in a title and do not carry any special meaning there, only when copied verbatim into markdown code.

Comment: Related: [ctrl + i to italicize does not always work right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103562/ctrl-i-to-italicize-does-not-always-work-right). Markdown doesn't seem to be escaped when necessary.

Comment: @JeremyBanks - How is that related?

Comment: @KevinVermeer: They're both caused by Markdown being automatically transformed naively as though it were plain text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build. We'll be escaping `[` and `]` as we already do for question titles inserted into the "possible duplicate..." comments.

Comment: Are those the only characters that can cause problems?

Comment: @Matthew - in this particular case, since it's the `[title](link)` format that blows up here.  We use that shorthand because the "Possible duplicate:" section needs to be completely self-contained.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info!  Congrats on 20k :P

Comment: Shouldn't *all markup* be escaped? For example, in [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11135461/3) a question with a python argument named `__code__` in the title is linked, and that is of course interpreted as markdown. Since titles are plain text, any markdown markup should be ignored.

Comment: Or better still, implement the [other answer to this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106828/140890) and not insert the title at all.

Answer (score 13):

There's an easy fix for this.  Instead of inserting this:

```
> **Possible Duplicate:**  
> [(![]+[])[+[]]&hellip; Explain why this works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170978/explain-why-this-works)  

<!-- End of automatically inserted text -->
```

Just insert this:

```
> **Possible Duplicate:**  
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170978/explain-why-this-works

<!-- End of automatically inserted text -->
```

The link gets displayed as the question title anyways (without needing to explicitly specify the title) like so:

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(![]+[])[+[]]... Explain why this works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170978/explain-why-this-works)

Comment: Using the direct link would also be possible to know when the duplicated question has been deleted; in that case, the link will not converted in a title.

Comment: Plus, this would make it easier to be consistent when editing in multiple duplicates.

Comment: +1 for this. [A question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717112/copying-and-reading-back-a-struct-instance-with-pointers-to-structures) was closed as duplicate whilst the thing it's a duplicate of was _very temporarily_ called "About to be deleted". This title was made semi-permanent in the dup banner until I went and modified it manually. Just insert `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170978`: keep the title out of it altogether.