# Duplicate link auto-edit breaks if question contains square bracket

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The title of the inserted link for a duplicate question should be properly escaped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104107/the-title-of-the-inserted-link-for-a-duplicate-question-should-be-properly-escape)

See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7377955/11343), marked as duplicate of a question that has square bracket in its title:

[image: Bug example]

Comment: Yep; voted to close, it's also a duplicate :)