# Community-inserted link got borked

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The title of the inserted link for a duplicate question should be properly escaped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104107/the-title-of-the-inserted-link-for-a-duplicate-question-should-be-properly-escape)

Over on [this edit](https://serverfault.com/revisions/237258/3)  on ServerFault Community seems to have "not finished" the dupe link.

[image]

Source:
[image]

Comment: It got borked because there was [some weird crap in the title](http://serverfault.com/posts/132998/revisions) of the duplicate question.